# How to prevent repeating actions on double click on the button?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Here are my actions in onClick(). The problem is that if I press the button twice, the new activity will be opened twice. I tried to use setEnabled() and setClickable(), but it does not work. It still shows more then one activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
CalendarActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("day", 16);
            intent.putExtra("month", 12);
            intent.putExtra("year", 1996);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CALENDAR_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a surprisingly complex problem. The root of the issue is that UI events (e.g. a button click) cause *messages* to be "posted" to the end of a message queue. If you are fast enough, it's possible to get many of these messages posted to the message queue before the first one is ever processed.

This means that even disabling the button inside your `onClick()` method won't truly solve the problem (since the disabling won't "happen" until the first message is processed, but you might already have three other duplicate messages waiting in the message queue).

The best thing to do is to track some sort of boolean flag and *check the flag every time* inside `onClick()`:

```
private boolean firstClick = true;
```

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (firstClick) {
        firstClick = false;
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

You have to remember to reset `firstClick` back to true whenever you want to re-enable button taps, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable the button from being clickable after the first time he was clicked:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //add this line
    button.setClickable(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("day", 16);
        intent.putExtra("month", 12);
        intent.putExtra("year", 1996);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CALENDAR_ACTIVITY_CODE);
    }
});
```

If this wont help you you can go to your activity in the manifest  and add this:

```
android:launchMode = "singleTop"
```

Comment: This will work as long as the clicks are slow enough that the first click is processed before the second click happens (because then the button will be un-clickable). But it is still possible to tap fast enough to enqueue two click events before the first is processed, and this won't cover that case. Of course, this solution might still be good enough for OP's needs.

Comment: I just looked at your answer below(very interesting)and I just want to ask, this may happen even with the  "singleTop" configuration in the manifest? I was sure that with this written inside the manifest it kind of covers this problem and prevent the activity to reopen again

Comment: `singleTop` changes _what happens_ when you call `startActivity[ForResult]()`, but does not change _whether or not_ your click listener is triggered multiple times. However, `singleTop` means that even if your click listener is triggered (let's say) three times, only one instance of the activity will be started (and then two new Intents will be delivered to that activity's `onNewIntent()` method).

Comment: This is why i love stack overflow - every day is a new chance to learn something new , that was really helpfull.

Comment: It reopens even with android:launchMode = "singleTop"

Comment: Look at the answer that  above - Ben p explains it really well

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue what you can do is use Jake Wharton
 Rxbinding library which allows you to convert your click  events to to stream.

You can add a throttle event which helps to stop the event from specified time

```
RxView.clicks(button).throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                        subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Object o) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Avoid multiple clicks using throttleFirst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Look at Ben P. answer - it is super simple and easy to unserstand