# Flag not touchable too slow for multiple clicks?

Tags: java, android, button

I made a keyboard out of buttons. When you press the wrong button, it creates a animation, same for the correct button. All of this works well. The problem is when the user press buttons like a maniac, just like in a fighting videogame. Then the animations will stop before finishing. To prevent this, I tried to set a FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE at the beginning of the moethod. But it doesn't really have any effect if you press buttons too fast.

```
    public void onClickKeyboard (View view) {

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);


    if (myAnswers[gameState].charAt(s.length())== ' ') {
          s = s + " ";
    }
        s = s + view.getTag().toString();

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(myAnswers[gameState].substring(0,s.length()))){

            ViewCompat.animate(view).alpha(0).setDuration(200).start();

            //  view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                preguntaViewInput = myQuestions[gameState] + s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+s.substring(1).toLowerCase();

            preguntaView.setText(preguntaViewInput, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        } else {

            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1); // sense aixo lapp crash quan sapreten 10 lletres incorrectes seguides
            b = (Button) view;

            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_keyboard_wrong);
            ViewCompat.animate(view).rotationBy(360).scaleY((float) 0.2).scaleX((float) 0.2).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ViewCompat.animate(b).rotationBy(360).scaleY((float) 1).scaleX((float) 1).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonpurchase);



                        }
                    });


                }
            });




        }




    if (s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myAnswers[gameState])) {
        Spannable ss = (Spannable) preguntaView.getText();

        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), myQuestions[gameState].length(), s.length() + myQuestions[gameState].length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        buttonNext.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(64, 0, 250, 0));
        String nextString = "correct";
        buttonNext.setText(nextString);
        buttonNext.setAlpha(0);
        buttonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewCompat.animate(buttonNext).alpha(1).setDuration(300).start();
    }


    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487518/how-to-prevent-repeating-actions-on-double-click-on-the-button/54487701#54487701) about multiple clicks, hope it helps

Comment: That would definetly help but I have a lot of buttons and I was looking for something more straightforward. Also I don't get why if there's a flag at the beginning and end this doesn't work well..

Comment: Can you put a picture of your custom keyboard?